# Focus on new row in a grid in automatic mode

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when I'm inserting a new row in a grid. The focus is always in up into left of the grid.
The problem is that when I insert more rows... the page returns in up and this is a inconvenient for the user .
My idea is set a focus for every new insert row ... the best mode ... would be to do a tab focus in specific cell of the new row(a field mandatory  Example Qta).

This my code in javascript:

```
   self.fromModel(data, self.CodArticolo, self.addingFromOrdineFornitore); 
         if (model.details.indexOf(self) == -1) { 
             model.details.splice(model.details.length - 1, 0, self);
```

Infact the function "splice" create a new rows popolate with a details of an article in the grid.... and this set the focus in the first cell in up into left

For try a test, I try to insert this code:

```
  var data = $("#Movimenti").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           var dataItem = data[i];
                  if (i == model.details.length - 2) {
$("#Movimenti").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]").effect("highlight", { color: "#f35800" }, 3000);
                                   }
                            }
```

And I can confirm that the find the correct rows and launching the effect that it works... but I don't find the solution for set the focus in the correct rows.

Can you help me? 
[image: visible problem description]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Add this code that resolved my case:

```
//Setto il focus all'interno dell'ultima riga inserita
                        var data = $("#Movimenti").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var dataItem = data[i];
                            if (i == model.details.length - 2) {
                                var grid = $("#Movimenti").data("kendoGrid");
                                //var firstCell = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "] td:first");
                                var cellName = "Qta";
                                var cellIndex_1 = grid.element.find("th[data-field = '" + cellName + "']").index();
                                var focusCell = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "] td:eq(" + cellIndex_1 + ")");

                                grid.current(focusCell);
                                focusCell.focus();
                                focusCell.trigger("click");
```

In this mode, I set a Focus and/or edit the specific cell ("Qta").
For me this case can to be closed

Best regards